Automatic Custom Map Updates
High level - A custom map is based on a database. I'm looking for a way for the custom map to automatically update when there's an update in a database.
Details - I'm currently using a custom Google My Maps to plot homes that are for sale. I'm updating an Airtable base with the property status (For Sale, Under Contract, Sold). I know I can simply update the Map as well when the status changes, but I'm trying to not have to update multiple things when a status changes. Because of this, I'm looking for a way for my custom map to reflect the dynamic database and update when the database updates.
If I mark a home as Under Contract in my database (wether it's in Airtable, Google Sheets, etc.), I'd like the custom map (wether it's Google My Maps or another tool) to automatically reflect the status change. If the color of the pin can change when the status changes that would be great. I also have custom fields associated with each house/map pin such as price, address, county, etc. So whatever tool I use will need this functionality.
I'm open to using any tools (both databases and mapping tools) to get this done. I'm also open to piecing together systems with Zapier or other similar tools.
Database - Airtable, Google Sheets, or open to other ideas if needed.
Mapping - Google My Maps and open to other ideas if needed.
I tried to hook Airtable together with Google My Maps through a Zap with Zapier, but Google My Maps is not supported by Zapier.

Have you tried using Integromat? I think this would be very useful when you apply a "Watch Records - Airtable" function on Maker to continuously monitor your records whenever you feel like changing them to "Under Contract" and then it triggers a change on the Google Maps, there are tons of ways to do this but this should be the easiest.
